# Loop on gebish test

Tags: loops, groovy, geb

I need use loop on gebish tests.
Example

```
def "refresh page with interval one min"() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    when:
      sleep 1000    
    then:
      println "=^_^="
  }
}
```

But i have nothing

Answer (score 4):

Your loop should go inside the spock blocks,

```
when:
    30.times{
        to MyPage
        sleep 1000           
    }
```